# systems of first degree equation, mathematics.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

which solutions of the
system?
observation: this system is determined.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeLWz.png

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: I want the solutions of the system, ie, x = ?, y = ?, z =? I want only the result of these variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By substituting $ x = -4y$ in the rest of the two equations you will get the below as the answer.The solution is $$x=0,y=0,z=0$$

Comment: here in the question, is reporting that this system is determined

Comment: did you get the same answer ?

Comment: No, because I realized that in the third equation there is a "z" missing, if I am not mistaken, when this happens, we put the number "1" in its place ..., the result gave nonzero.

Comment: If the z is missing then you put a zero there not 1

Comment: ah! got it! thank you!